# AJAX page load/url with parameter causing blank page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

Good afternoon,

I am working on a website for a friend's gaming fansite.  Utilizing a URI function and ajax URL loads, I'm setting it up so when they visit a page, the URL changes and that page's content loads, while leaving the top portion of the website static.  The logo, radio box and navigation bar is the static portion.

Everything is working as intended so far, but when a page is used that's using a specific ID, it loads up a blank page.  I'll show what I've done with the Badges page for an example.

Here's my **HTACCESS**:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^badges/([0-9]+)/?$ badges.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Here's the **URI** script:

```
<?php
  function getCurrentUri() {
      $basepath = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, -1)) . '/';
      $uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($basepath));
      if (strstr($uri, '?')) $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
      $uri = '/' . trim($uri, '/');
      return $uri;
  }
  $base_url = getCurrentUri();
  $routes = array();
  $routes = explode('/', $base_url);
  foreach($routes as $route) {
      if(trim($route) != '')
          array_push($routes, $route);
  }
  if ($base_url == "/" || $base_url == "/home") {
      $page = "home";
  } elseif ($base_url == "/about") {
      $page = "about";
  } elseif ($base_url == "/badges") {
      $page = "badges";
  }
?>
```

Here's my **AJAX** call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $page; ?>.php',
            success: function(content) {
                $("#contfill").html(content);
                history.pushState(null, '', '<?php echo $page; ?>');
                homePageInit();
            }
        });
});
```

When www.domain.com/badges is used, it loads the page correctly as shown here:

[image: Badge page working correctly]

The first badge's ID is 324.  When www.domain.com/badges/324 is used, it loads the data correctly, but the page is blank as shown here:

[image: Badge page not working correctly]

Does anyone know why this would be?

**EDIT**

I added in a alert('$base_url'); to see what it would be. When using www.domain.com/badges, it shows as /badges. When using www.domain.com/badges/324 no alert pops up, so it seems that it's going directly to badges.php. Is that due to the HTACCESS?

**SECOND EDIT**

Here is my **badges.php** script:

```
<?php require('../panel/includes/config.php'); ?>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading bg-color-blue">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Badge Guides</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>
                  <img src="assets/images/1badge_guides.png" alt="Guides" class="img-responsive img-center">
                  <?php
                    if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
                        $id = $_GET["id"];
                        $newsQuery = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=:id");
                        $newsQuery->execute(array(":id"=>$id));
                        $newsQueryData = $newsQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                  ?>
                  <br>
                  <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://habbfinity.ca/badge.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&text=New badge guide posted!" class="btn btn-info">Tweet</a>
                  <br>
                  <?php
                        echo htmlspecialchars_decode($newsQueryData['article']);
                    } else {
                        $reqInfo2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT n.id,
                                                       n.image,
                                                       n.title,
                                                       n.category,
                                                       n.description,
                                                       n.article,
                                                       n.active,
                                                       n.level,
                                                       n.available,
                                                       n.author,
                                                       n.stamp,
                                                       c.cat_num,
                                                       c.cat_name,
                                                       a.active_num,
                                                       a.active_name,
                                                       av.avail_num,
                                                       av.avail_name,
                                                       l.level_num,
                                                       l.level_name
                                                FROM news n
                                                INNER JOIN news_cat c
                                                    ON n.category = c.cat_num
                                                INNER JOIN active_cat a
                                                    ON n.active = a.active_num
                                                INNER JOIN avail_cat av
                                                    ON n.available = av.avail_num
                                                INNER JOIN level_cat l
                                                    ON n.level = l.level_num
                                                WHERE n.category = 10 AND n.active = 1
                                                ORDER BY n.stamp DESC");
                        $reqInfo2->execute();
                  ?>
                  <p class="text-center">
                    <strong>BADGE GUIDES</strong>
                  </p>
                  <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Badge</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Level</th>
                        <th>Availability</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <?php
                        while ($reqInfoData = $reqInfo2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                      ?>
                      <tr class="bg-success">
                        <td><?php echo "<img src=\"{$reqInfoData['image']}\" class=\"img-responsive\">"; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo "<a href=\"#badge\" id=\"badge\" value=\"{$reqInfoData['id']}\">{$reqInfoData['title']}</a>"; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $reqInfoData['description']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $reqInfoData['level_name']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                          <?php
                            if ($reqInfoData['avail_name'] == "Available") {
                                echo "<span style=\"color: green;\">{$reqInfoData['avail_name']}</span>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<span style=\"color: red;\">{$reqInfoData['avail_name']}</span>";
                            }
                          ?>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <?php
                        }
                      ?>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <?php
                    }
                  ?>
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the **index.php** page:

```
<?php
  function getCurrentUri() {
      $basepath = implode('/', array_slice(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, -1)) . '/';
      $uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($basepath));
      if (strstr($uri, '?')) $uri = substr($uri, 0, strpos($uri, '?'));
      $uri = '/' . trim($uri, '/');
      return $uri;
  }
  $base_url = getCurrentUri();
  $routes = array();
  $routes = explode('/', $base_url);
  foreach($routes as $route) {
      if(trim($route) != '')
          array_push($routes, $route);
  }
  if ($base_url == "/" || $base_url == "/home") {
      $page = "home";
  } elseif ($base_url == "/about") {
      $page = "about";
  } elseif ($base_url == "/badges") {
      $page = "badges";
  }
  require('../panel/includes/config.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Habbfinity</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/custom.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper" class="container well">
      <header>
        <section id="brand" class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <img src="assets/images/habbfinitylogo.png" alt="Habbfinity" class="img-responsive img-center">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default radpan">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <?php
                  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
                  $timecheck = date("H:00");
                  $timecheckwhour = strtotime($timecheck) + 60*60;
                  $newtimecheck = date("H:00", $timecheckwhour);
                  $daycheck = date("N");
                  $djQuery = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE day=:day AND time=:time");
                  $djQuery->execute(array(":day"=>$daycheck, ":time"=>$timecheck));
                  $djQueryData = $djQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                  if (isset($djQueryData) || $djQueryData != "") {
                      $djQuery2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE djname=:dj");
                      $djQuery2->execute(array(":dj"=>$djQueryData['dj']));
                      $djQueryData2 = $djQuery2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                  }
                  $djQuery3 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE day=:day AND time=:time");
                  $djQuery3->execute(array(":day"=>$daycheck, ":time"=>$newtimecheck));
                  $djQuery3Data = $djQuery3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                  if (isset($djQuery3Data) || $djQuery3Data != "") {
                      $djQuery4 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE djname=:dj");
                      $djQuery4->execute(array(":dj"=>$djQuery3Data['dj']));
                      $djQueryData4 = $djQuery4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                  }
                  $djSays = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM dj_says ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
                  $djSays->execute();
                  $djSaysData = $djSays->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                ?>
                <audio autoplay id="player">
                  <source src="http://procyon.shoutca.st:8930/stream" type="audio/mp4">
                  <source src="http://procyon.shoutca.st:8930/stream" type="audio/ogg">
                </audio>
                <form method="post">
                  <p class="text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-trans" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"><i class="fa fa-play galaxy" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-trans" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()"><i class="fa fa-pause galaxy" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-trans" onclick="javascript:ajaxpage('requests.php', 'contfill');"><i class="fa fa-comment galaxy" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-trans" value="like" name="like"><i class="fa fa-heart galaxy" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?hb=image&user=augmented_Runes&headonly=0&direction=4&head_direction=2&action=wav&gesture=&size=m" class="img-responsive img-center">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-9">
                        <i class="fa fa-music" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span id="cc_strinfo_song_Habbfinity00" class="cc_streaminfo"></span>
                        <br>
                        <i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span id="cc_strinfo_listeners_Habbfinity00" class="cc_streaminfo"></span> Listeners
                        <br>
                        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span id="cc_strinfo_title_Habbfinity00" class="cc_streaminfo"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p class="marquee2">
                          <span><?php echo $djSaysData['message']; ?></span>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                        <input id="vol-control" class="myrange" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="SetVolume(this.value)" onchange="SetVolume(this.value)"></input>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </p>
                </form>
                <?php
                  if (isset($_POST['like']) && isset($djQueryData2['habbo']) && $djQueryData2['habbo'] != "") {
                      $dj = $djQueryData2['habbo'];
                      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                      $cur_time = time();
                      $djLikes = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM djlikes WHERE dj=:dj AND likedip=:ip");
                      $djLikes->execute(array(":dj"=>$dj, ":ip"=>$ip));
                      $djLikesData = $djLikes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                      if ($djLikesData['likedip'] != "") {
                          $lasttime = $djLikesData['lastliked'];
                          $diff = abs($cur_time - $lasttime);
                          if ($diff > 3600) {
                              $AddLikes = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE djlikes SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE likedip=:ip");
                              $AddLikes->execute(array(":ip"=>$ip));
                              echo "Thank you for liking the DJ!";
                          } else {
                              echo "Please wait an hour before liking the DJ again!";
                          }
                      } else {
                          $AddLikes = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO djlikes VALUES (:habbo, :time:, :ip, 1)");
                          $AddLikes->execute(array(":habbo"=>$djQueryData2['habbo'], ":time"=>$cur_time, ":ip"=>$ip));
                          echo "Thank you for liking the DJ!";
                      }
                  }
                ?>
              </div>
              <div class="radimageoverdiv"><i class="fa fa-rocket galaxyl" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#home" id="home"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> HOME</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> HABBFINITY <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#about" id="about">About Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#staff" id="staff">Our Team</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contactus" id="contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#sitenews" id="sitenews">Site News</a></li>
                  <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Habbfinity" target="_blank">Follow Our Twitter!</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> QUEST <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#badges" id="badges">Badge Guides</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#wired" id="wired">Wired Guides</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#news" id="news">News</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-gamepad" aria-hidden="true"></i> EVENTS <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#events" id="events">Events Timetable</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#howto" id="howto">How To Play</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i> RADIO <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#radio" id="radio">Radio Timetable</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#requests" id="requests">Request Line</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> GOODIES <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#HabboImager">Habbo Imager</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="https://www.habbfinity.ca/forum/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> FORUM</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <div id="contfill">
      </div>
      <a id="back-to-top" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg back-to-top" role="button" title="Click to return on the top page" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="HabboImager">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Habbo Imager</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <?php include 'imager.php'; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="imagerscript.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://procyon.shoutca.st/system/streaminfo.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.SetVolume = function(val) {
          var player = document.getElementById('player');
          player.volume = val / 100;
      }
      function homePageInit() {
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
          $(window).scroll(function() {
              if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                  $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
              } else {
                  $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
              }
          });
          $('#back-to-top').click(function() {
              $('#back-to-top').tooltip('hide');
              $('body,html').animate({
                  scrollTop: 0
              }, 800);
              return false;
          });
          $('#back-to-top').tooltip('show');
          var badgeUrl = 'http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/c_images/album1584/';
          $.getJSON( 'http://habboemotion.com/api/badge', function( badges ) {
              $.each( badges.list, function( key, badge ) {
                  $('div#badges').append('<img src="'+badgeUrl+badge.code+'.gif" class="thumbnail aleft" alt="Badge" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'+badge.name+' - '+badge.desc+'">');
                  return (key !== 11);
              });
          });
          $.getScript('https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', function() {

          });
          $.getScript('http://habbfinity.ca/forum/external.php?type=js', function() {
              var str = "";
              for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                  str += "<a href=\"http://habbfinity.ca/forum/showthread.php?t="+threads[x].threadid+"\" target=\"_blank\">"+threads[x].title+"</a> <br>(Posted By: "+threads[x].poster+")<br><br />";
              }
              $("#habbfinity_forum").html(str);
              console.log(str);
          });
      }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $page; ?>.php',
            success: function(content) {
                $("#contfill").html(content);
                history.pushState(null, '', '<?php echo $page; ?>');
                homePageInit();
            }
        });
        $('#home').on("click", function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'home.php',
                success: function(content) {
                    $("#contfill").html(content);
                    history.pushState(null, '', 'home');
                    homePageInit();
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $('#about').on("click", function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'about.php',
                success: function(content) {
                    $("#contfill").html(content);
                    history.pushState(null, '', 'about');
                    homePageInit();
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $('#badges').on("click", function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'badges.php',
                success: function(content) {
                    $("#contfill").html(content);
                    history.pushState(null, '', 'badges');
                    homePageInit();
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you check the value of $base_url when an ID is used?

Comment: Hi khartnett.  I added in a <script>alert('$base_url');</script> to see what it would be.  When using www.domain.com/badges, it shows as /badges.  When using www.domain.com/badges/324 no alert pops up, so it seems that it's going directly to badges.php.  Is that due to the HTACCESS?

Comment: sounds possible. I'm curious about the content on your 'blank' page. Do you know where this comes from? is there a badges.php on the server?

Comment: Hi khartnett.  The badges.php page, in the first screenshot, just lists each badge if no ID is used.  The badges.php page, in the second screenshot, should just show the data for the specific badge if ID is used, which it's doing, but it looks like it's only loading badges.php, not the entire document, as each page should be loading into a DIV called "contfill".

Comment: are there any errors in your browser console? You should be able to view the output of your php there as well

Comment: No errors are showing up when I visit www.domain.com/badges/324.  It seems to just be completely skipping over the whole index document.  I'll go ahead and edit my question to include index and the badges page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174908/discussion-between-khartnett-and-morgan-klaif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing in chat, the solution was to remove the `RewriteRule ^badges/([0-9]+)/?$ badges.php?id=$1 [L]` from the htaccess. Any url that doesn't have a .php renders only the content portion of #contfill.

We then needed to modify the url the ajax uses in index.php, to convert the route from '/badges/324' to '/badges.php?id=324'